# Change image of button which have some style

Tags: wpf, button, styles

i created a style in App.xaml file for button

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="controlButtonFavourite" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="imgButtonBackground" Source="/WpfApp;component/Media%20Images/MediaNavigationButtonBackground.png" Stretch="Uniform"></Image>
                <Image x:Name="imgNavigationButtonTypeFavourite" Source="/WpfApp;component/Media%20Images/MediaFav_White.png" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="9"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="imgNavigationButtonTypeFavourite" Property="Source" Value="/WpfApp;component/Media%20Images/MediaFav_Gold.png" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Now i want to change the image of **imgNavigationButtonTypeFavourite** at run time for specific condition. i am unable to figure out that how can i change this image. Please suggest that how it is possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit from `Button` and add a dependency property for the image path. This property can be used in the `ControlTemplate`.

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImagePathProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImagePath", typeof (string), typeof (ImageButton));

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(ImagePathProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImagePathProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Usage of the button:

```
<ImageButton x:Name="imageButton" ImagePath="..." />
```

Code behind usage:

```
imageButton.ImagePath = "...";
```

Usage in the template:

```
<Setter TargetName="imgNavigationButtonTypeFavourite" Property="Source" Value="{TemplateBinding ImagePath}" />
```

Comment: Yes i can, but i want to use style from App.xaml as described in my question. So there are any chance to change image ?

Comment: With my suggestion you can define the style in the App.xaml, but have to define the ImagePaths when using the control. Another way would be to use the Triggers or VisualStates for the control, but then you couldn't react to all your application specific conditions.